Iterating through ChildContent in Blazor
I'm trying to achieve something like this using Blazor and MudBlazor:
MainPage.razor
<Section>
   <MudTextField ... />
   <MudTimePicker ... />
   <MudNumericField ... />
</Section>

Section.razor
@for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i += 2)
{
    <div style="width:50%">
        @Children[i]
    </div>
    @if (i + 1 < Children.Count)
    {
        <div style="width:50%">
            @Children[i + 1]
        </div>
    }
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public required RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private List<RenderFragment> Children = new();

    private void ProcessChildContent()
    {
        // some transformation to get all children and be able to iterate through them
        // any other idea is also good as long as HTML stays like above
    }
}

Is something like this even possible in Blazor?
I tried already iterating through frames using RenderTreeBuilder but failed. I don't know if this is the right approach. Using different props for each child won't do, because I'd like to pass unknown amount of children. I tried also this twice but once I got error because of lacking ChildContent Prop and another time all children were re-rendered each time browser window was dragged, resized or any input changed. HashSet instead of List seemed to solve it but overall it doesn't look like the right approach to me.

It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you explain your requirements without the code? What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better approach you see, but it's hard to work out from the current code.

No.  You don't iterate through objects like you would with the DOM in JavaScript.  You iterate through lists of data, and you use the markup to EXPRESS the data.

1. If you only want to set the child components into diferent areas of
section.razor:
Caller Component:
<Section>
    <Left>
        <MudTextField ... />
        <MudNumericField ... />
    </Left>
    <Right>
        <MudTimePicker ... />
    </Right>
</Section>

Section Component:
<div style="width:50%">
    @Left
</div>
<div style="width:50%">
    @Right
</div>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public required RenderFragment Left { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public required RenderFragment Right { get; set; }
}

2. If you need to iterate through the Childs
Section.razor
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div style="width:50%">
        @Left
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%">
        @Right
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
            
@code{
    public List<ComponentBase> Childs { get; } = new List<ComponentBase>();

    private InterateChilds()
    {
        foreach(ComponentBase child in Childs)
        {
            if (child is ExtendedMudTextField)
            {
                (child as ExtendedMudTextField).PROPERTY = xyz;
            }
        }
    }
}

ExtendedMudTextField.razor
@inherits MudTextField

@RenderBase()

@code {
    RenderFragment RenderBase() => base.BuildRenderTree;
    
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Section Parent { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Parent.Childs.Add(this);
    }
}


Sometimes showing a question asker how to do what they should not be doing will just slow their development.
